# How to enter keys into array using defined ranges?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, php-5.3, date-range

So I have code that outputs the following:

```
$test = array('test1.txt' => '1 June 2015',
               'test2.txt' => '1 June 2015',
               'test3.txt' => '1 June 2015',
               'test4.txt' => '1 June 2015',
               'test5.txt' => '1 June 2015');
```

But instead of 5 files there are hundreds. How would I make it so the I can define the date outputted depending on the line number i.e.

If file 1-5 (first 5 files), then date = "1 June 2015". If file 6-8 (next 2 files), then date = "5 June 2015. Etc. Etc. How would I go about doing so?

Comment: How are you defining your range. or on what basis you have your range

Comment: The number of files are fixed or they may vary? Or how the number will be defined?

Comment: `$date = $test['test'.$n.'.txt']` where `$n = filenumber `

Comment: The number of files may vary. The dates are defined manually by me for range (i.e. i define 1 date for first 5 files, define another for next 2, etc. etc.)

Comment: Then how one can decide the number of files? There must be some way that tell about that!!

Comment: Okay, then assume number of files is fixed.

Comment: First five and then two? For 100 files?

Comment: I should be able to define how many files, date for each file range and file range itself. Example first 5, then 2 but I can also do others like for First 50, set date as X and for next 10 after that set date as Y

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
$date = "1 June 2015"; // The initial date
$fileNum = array(5, 2, 3); // The number of files to be considered
$total = array_sum($fileNum); // Total number of files
$array = array(); // Array to be filled
$j = 1; // The number for increment
foreach($fileNum as $num) {
    $i = 1; // The number to compare the file numbers 
    while($i <= $num) {
         $array['test' . $j . '.txt'] = $date; // Store the values
         $j++;
         $i++;
    }
    $date = date('j F Y', strtotime('+ 1 DAY', strtotime($date))); // Increment the date
}

var_dump($array);
```

**Output**

```
array(10) {
  ["test1.txt"]=>
  string(11) "1 June 2015"
  ["test2.txt"]=>
  string(11) "1 June 2015"
  ["test3.txt"]=>
  string(11) "1 June 2015"
  ["test4.txt"]=>
  string(11) "1 June 2015"
  ["test5.txt"]=>
  string(11) "1 June 2015"
  ["test6.txt"]=>
  string(11) "2 June 2015"
  ["test7.txt"]=>
  string(11) "2 June 2015"
  ["test8.txt"]=>
  string(11) "3 June 2015"
  ["test9.txt"]=>
  string(11) "3 June 2015"
  ["test10.txt"]=>
  string(11) "3 June 2015"
}
```

**Update**

```
$fileNum = array(5 => "1 June 2015", 2 => "2 June 2015", 3 => "3 June 2015"); // Set the array with file number and corresponding dates
$total = array_sum($fileNum);
$array = array();
$j = 1;
foreach($fileNum as $num => $date) {
    $i = 1;
    while($i <= $num) {
         $array['test' . $j . '.txt'] = $date;
         $j++;
         $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. This is my actual code, can it integrate with this? $path = "/home/files/";
$date = "1 June 2015";
$files = array();foreach (glob($path . "*.txt") as $filename) {    
$files[$filename] = "";

var_export($files);

Comment: What does array(5, 2, 3) do? How would I go about doing that? Sorry, I am quite a beginner when it comes to PHP.

Comment: It is the number of files.

Comment: I don't want to increment dates by 1 I want to define using something like this: $files1to5 = "1 June 2015"; $files6to8 = "2 June 2015"; $files9to50 = "11 June 2015";

Comment: I ran the code but it had no output. How would I add my "$files" array in the code $path = "/home/files/"; $date = "1 June 2015"; $files = array();foreach (glob($path . "*.txt") as $filename) { $files[$filename] = ""; var_export($files);

Comment: Try to figure out what is wrong with the code. We cant help you step by step.

Comment: Ok, I'm testing it but still confused of array(5, 2, 3)? What does 5 mean, 2 mean and 3 mean? Where do I define my file range?

Comment: 5 files, 2 files, 3 files

Comment: I ran the script with 50 .txt files, but all the key values are being set to "3 June 2015" - do you know why this happens?

Comment: Hey, instead of defining the dates, how would it possible to just increment by 1 day? I tested the original code but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
  $numberOfFiles = 100;
//$startDate = '1 June 2015';

$startDate = '1 June 2015';
for($i=1;$i<=$numberOfFiles;$i++)
{
    if($i%5==0)
    {
        $test['test'.$i.'.txt'] = $startDate;
        $startDate = date('j F Y',strtotime($startDate.' + 5 days'));
    }
    else
    {
        $test['test'.$i.'.txt'] = $startDate;
    } 
}

print_r($test);
```

Updated to requirement.
Note You have to define the date against file number.

```
$numberOfFiles = 50;
//$startDate = '1 June 2015';

for($i=1;$i<=$numberOfFiles;$i++)
{
    if($i<=5)
    {
        $startDate ='1 June 2015';
        $test['test'.$i.'.txt'] = $startDate;
    }
    elseif((5<$i)&&($i<=8))
    {
        $startDate ='2 June 2015';
        $test['test'.$i.'.txt'] = $startDate;
    }
    elseif((8<$i)&&($i<=50))
    {
        $startDate ='11 June 2015';
        $test['test'.$i.'.txt'] = $startDate;
    }
    else
    {
        // Define the date value if does not match above criterian
    } 
}

print_r($test);
```

Comment: Are you sure the number of files will be `5`?

Comment: Need a specific pattern to increment date against file number.

Comment: Thanks! I'm testing it out right now, will comment back results